# Matrix to the power n equals a matrix, solve it for n

Tags: matrices, logarithms, exponentiation, matrix-equations

How to solve the equation $$\mathbf{A}^n=\mathbf{B}$$ for $n$, where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are given real square matrices? (Formally something like the logarithm would be needed, but instead of the usual interpretation of matrix logarithm, here the *base* is a matrix.)

Comment: There exists matrix logarithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix

Comment: Although often we need to choose a *branch* as such equations can have many different solutions.

Comment: The value of $n$ depends on $A$ and  $B$. (How to solve this also depends on $A$ and $B$; for example _if_ $\det(A)\ne0$ it's easy.) What are $A$ and $B$???

Comment: @mathreadler The usual matrix logarithm solves the equation $e^{\mathbf{A}}=\mathbf{B}$, i.e., the base is a scalar and the exponent is a matrix. Here, the base should be a matrix (formally).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Good questions. If the equation can only be solved if the matrices meet some constraints, it'd be interesting to know what these constraints are.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What is that easy solution if $\mathrm{det}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)\neq0$...?

Comment: Hint: $\det(A^n)=\det(A)^n$.

Comment: Arrrgh, I see... $n=\log_{\mathrm{det}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}\mathrm{det}\left(\mathbf{B}\right)$... right? Thanks! However, if really that is what you mean, then we have a problem with $\mathrm{det}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)<0$, not only with $\mathrm{det}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)=0$...

Comment: Exp is defined as a matrix function. $\exp({\bf A}) = {\bf B}$, and this matrix valued exponential function taking a matrix as an argument should fulfill the exponential law with respect to a scalar just like normally $\exp(k{\bf A}) = \exp(k)\exp({\bf A})$

Comment: If n is required to be a natural number, there may well be no solution at all. We can always find an m x m invertible complex P such that M= P^{-1}AP has the eigenvaues  of A on the leading diagonal, possibly some 1's on the super-diagonal and 0's elsewhere. Then A^{n}=PM^{n}P^{-1}=B, so M^{n}=P^{-1}BP , which is impossible if P^{-1}BP is not upper triangular.

Comment: A necessary condition for a solution to exist is $AB=BA$. As said before, if the solution exists, the same equation must hold for the determinants, so if they are nonzero, there's at most one solution candidate, and just check if it's indeed a solution.

Comment: @mathreadler Surely I overlook something (possibly) trivial, but I don't see how this exponential law helps us in solving this equation.

Comment: @P.Lawrence No, $n$ need not to be a natural number it can be any positive real number.

Comment: @TamasFerenci you will need to first define matrix power for non-integers, then.

Answer (score 0):

This I'm afraid isn't always numerically solvable, especially in the presence of round-off errors.

E.g. consider the case where $A$ is a $2\times2$ rotation matrix for an angle $\theta$. Then $B$ is also a rotation matrix for an angle $\phi$. The problem then reduces to solving $n\theta=\phi+2m\pi$ for integers $n$ and $m$. Numerically, we can perhaps find a sequence $\{(n_k,m_k)\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ such that $|n_k\theta-\phi-2m_k\pi|$ is arbitrarily small, but the problem is that the sequence $\{(n_k,m_k)\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ itself doesn't converge, and so we don't know which $n_k$ is close to the true value of $n$.

However, if $A$ possesses a nonzero eigenvalue of modulus $\ne1$, we may obtain $n$ from $\frac{\log|\lambda|^n}{\log|\lambda|}$. That is, if $A=PJP^{-1}$ where $J$ is the Jordan form of $A$ and $\lambda_i$ is the $i$-th diagonal entry of $J$, then $n=\frac{\log|(P^{-1}BP)_{ii}|}{\log|\lambda_i|}$ when $|\lambda_i|\ne0,1$.

If $J$ has a nilpotent Jordan block and the corresponding diagonal sub-block in $P^{-1}BP$ is nonzero, we may also read off $n$ directly from the position of the super-diagonal of that diagonal sub-block.